# Multiples condiciones usando CASE

Tags: sql, usecase

tengo el siguiente query que suma cada que es mayor que 0 cada campo:

```
SUM(CASE when h.windows_b > 0 then h.scal end)/15 as Windows_b_only,
SUM(case when h.windows_c > 0 then h.scal end)/15 as Windows_c_only,
SUM(case when h.windows_o > 0 then h.scal end)/15 as Windows_o_only
```

Quiero conocer la suma de aquellos que  tengan mas de uno en los diferentes campos, por ejemplo si es mayor que 0 en windows_b y mayor que 0 en windows_c O windows_o entonces sumar

Tengo lo siguiente para hacerlo pero no esta funcionando:

```
SUM(CASE when h.windows_b > 0 AND (h.windows_c > 0 OR  h.windows_o > 0)
         then h.scal/15
         when h.windows_c > 0 AND (h.windows_b > 0 OR  h.windows_o > 0)
         then h.scal/15
         when h.windows_o > 0 AND (h.windows_c > 0 OR  h.windows_b > 0)
         then h.scal/15 end) as Multiple_only
```

Comment: Bienvenido Jozamvg a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega por favor como etiqueta el motor de base de datos y en lo posible el query completo. Saludos.

Comment: Explica lo que quieres decir con "no está funcionando". Lo probé y funciona perfecto. Al menos funciona si hablamos del CASE. Es probable que estés teniendo un problema de división de enteros que no se mostraba cuando la división se hacía a la sumatoria y no a los valores individuales.